# How can I play a video without causing music on iTunes/other audio to pause

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play a video (open to alternative players). My videos don't have sound. When the video starts, if the IOS device is playing music/audio of some sort, the music/audio pauses even though the video has no sound.

Is there any way to continue playing music while playing a silent movie?

Comment: Have you changed your `AVSession` mode?  If not, look into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try preparing the audio session before starting playback:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];

//... create & configure AVPlayer and start playback
```

Comment: FYI - this worked for me, too (similar):[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&activationError];
    if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&sessionError]) {
        NSLog(@"[AppDelegate] Failed to setup audio session: %@", sessionError);
    }